# How do you check the class of a Python csv.writer instance?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have a function that will write a python list to various formats.  `csv` is one of the formats I would like to write out to.  I know i use the built-in `csv` Python module, but my function is currently written in the following manner:

```
def foo(self, save_to=None):
    if save_to is None:
        print self.my_list
```

I can check the type of the csv.writer object by doing:

```
writer = csv.writer(open('test.csv','w'))
writer
<_csv.writer at 0x7f278125aca8>    

type(writer)
_csv.writer
```

How do I check to see in my function if `save_to` is an `csv` object?  Usually I'd use the `isinstance` in a function function like such:

```
def foo(self, save_to=None):
    if save_to is None:
        print self.my_list
    if isinstance(save_to, _csv.writer):
        save_to.writerow([self.my_list])
```

but I'm getting a `NameError` and `AttrubuteError`

```
In [28]: isinstance(writer, _csv.writer)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-0af1f54bd092> in <module>()
----> 1 isinstance(writer, _csv.writer)    

NameError: name '_csv' is not defined    

In [29]: isinstance(writer, csv._csv.writer)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-4e8e62254caf> in <module>()
----> 1 isinstance(writer, csv._csv.writer)    

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use an `isinstance` check here (and especially not with a class in a  private module like `_csv`): `isinstance` calls violate OOP in general. More specific to Python, its "duck-typing" means that you should just try and use the method and catch attribute errors: if it quacks like a duck, it's a duck -- if it implements `writerow` like a csv writer, it's a csv writer.

```
try:
    save_to.writerow([self.my_list])
except AttributeError:
    # not a csv writer, do something else
```

More specifically though, the reason you're getting the errors you detail is because the submodule isn't imported.

Comment: thanks!  would it then be appropriate (good practice) to put a `pass` in the `except` so I don't end up nesting a `try`/`except`s if I potentially want this function to be generic and (easily) extendable?

Comment: Well, since this is in a function that doesn't seem to return anything, I'd just put a `return` in the `except` block, so that you know that branch of the essentially conditional logic is done with. But otherwise, sure, you could put a pass there (or maybe a logging statement, since suppressing exceptions silently is a recipe for hard-to-diagnose bugs).